# date format jquery with common output format from date

Tags: jquery

some time my date is `2014-08-01` and some time `01-08-2014` 
but i need the output is common format like `01-08-2014`
the `regdate.split("-")` is not suitable for this above input.
 I'm left using a client side method anyway to do in jquery to get common output date format
`01-08-2014`

Comment: does you only want your yyyy-mm-dd and dd-mm-yyyy format to be changed to dd-mm-yyyy. Is there any format such as mm-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var day = myDate.getDate();
var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = myDate.getFullYear();
if (day < 10) {
    day = "0" + day;
}
if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month;
}
var formattedDate = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
```

This will give you output date in format `DD-MM-YYYY` regardless of the date you receive from server.

Comment: var myDate = new Date("01-10-2014"); answer is NaN/NaN/NaN why

Comment: @DhanushBala It must be invalid date or something. see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b78V6/1/)

Comment: @DhanushBala It takes '2014-08-01' as Jan 8th. So you are getting wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Use Separate plugin `Jquery UI` for Date format.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('span.date').each(function() { 
    var dateFormat = $(this).text()
    var dateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd, yy', new Date(dateFormat));
    //alert(dateFormat);
    $(this).html(dateFormat + "<br>");
});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamculpepper/rHXcp/)

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here's one specific for your code:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

More general info available here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
var xdate = new Date();

$(this).html(xdate.toLocaleDateString() + "<br>");
```

This gives the same result for the current date.